# "Alternative of, for" or "to"

Tags: grammar, word-choice, prepositions

Can somebody help me with **this** sentence? It is really needy!

> *An alternative (**for**, **of**, **to**) working out is to go for a walk.*

Comment: An alternative to working out is **going** for a walk.

Answer (score 3):

> An alternative to working out is to go for a walk.

This simply means "go for a walk" is something else to do instead of working out.  This is the most neutral and safest choice.

> An alternative for working out is to go for a walk.

*For* makes it seem like you are not directly involved in what's going on here.   One example situation is this: you are preparing a list of things for someone else to do, and wanting to change one of the items in the list.

> An alternative of working out is to go for a walk.

*Of* makes it seem like "go for a walk" was previously identified as a backup for "working out" and you can select between the two.

Answer (score 2):

[Oxford Free Online Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/alternative) doesn't explain preposition usage, but they do have examples showing the use of "to" after "alternative" when it's used as a noun:

> Audiobooks are an interesting alternative to reading.

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/alternative) has similar examples:

> an alternative to coffee

The idiomatically correct choice would be:

> An alternative to working out is to go for a walk. (Correct, but may need stylistic improvement.)

There's a notion of [parallelism](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/623/1/). I am not sure that is the correct terminology here but I believe it is. In short, parallelism says to match gerunds with gerunds, infinitives with infinitives and nouns with nouns. These sentences follow that stylistic guide:

> An alternative to working out is going for a walk.
>
> An alternative to work out is to go for a walk.

Answer (score -1):

An alternative to working out is going for a walk.

Comment: Can you defend the answer--otherwise it just repeats a comment, with even less explanation.

Comment: Two problems with this answer. (1) It contains, word-for-word, Edwin Ashworth's comment on the question. The quotation was used without marking it as a quotation or crediting the author. (2) "Remember, you … have to write an actual answer, in your own words. A post that consists only of copied text, even when attributed, is not your work”. “Use quotes sparingly, to support your own words.” See: “[Users are calling me a plagiarist. What do I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160077)”